# Indexação de página que pode redirecionar

Tags: seo, web-crawler, google-analytics-api

Tenho um determinado site que contem algumas páginas, porém algumas dessas páginas não estão sendo indexadas pelo Google.

Porém as paginas que o Google não indexa não podem ser acessadas se não for escolhida uma determinada opção antes acessar as mesmas.

#### Por exemplo:

Se o cara entrar na página `/page1` será verificado no *local storage* do cliente se há salvo uma determinada configuração, caso esteja já configurada é prosseguido para `/page1` se não ele será redirecionado para a uma determinada `/homepage` onde o usuário vai definir esta configuração e após isso é levado a `/page1` novamente.

Neste cenário, seria isso que está causando a não indexação destas páginas?

Comment: Acredito que o bot do Google se comporta como um usuário comum, então se a página só é acessível depois de um cadastra por exemplo, é de se esperar que o Bot realmente não a indexe, pois ele não vai preencher o cadastro do seu site, assim não tem acesso a página, assim não tem como indexa-la...

Comment: É, eu imaginei isto, porém ainda não consegui achar algo que comprove antes de mudar tudo. Mas tenho 90% de certeza que seja isso mesmo....

Comment: Não tenho fonte de referência, mas vai pesquisando ai que deve ter algo documentado sobre isso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou te dar uma resposta que acho que pode te esclarecer alguns pontos. Apesar disso pode ser que não seja a resposta exata para o seu problema, no entenda pode te ajudar a eliminar algumas hipóteses.

Primeiro, em alguns casos o Bot do Google preenche sim, formulários e outros tipos de `input`, mas ele só faz isso se detectar que pode haver algum conteúdo de interesse. Como o Google interpreta esse "interesse" isso só os engenheiros do Google podem te responder. Mas vc pode consultar detalhes nesse vídeo do **Google Webmasters**, veja a partir do minuto 29 https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1751&v=QWL864VlW7I

Visto isso tenha em mente que mesmo que o Bot tenha a intenção de preencher os campos esses campos precisam ser amigáveis para o Bot, isso quer dizer que não devem por exemplo ser campos de dados pessoais, incluindo cartões de crédito, cpf, senhas etc.

> Google will decide on an individual basis if a `FORM-Element` on a page is considered to be useful and then try to fill out that form using a small number of different natural requests, made to simulate an actual user.
>
> Google only crawls `forms` which use the `GET-method` and do not ask for personal information. **Additionally, the form should be made up of no more than two input fields**.

***Tradução***

*"O **Google** decidirá individualmente se um Elemento `FORM` em uma página for considerado útil e tentará preencher esse formulário usando um pequeno número de solicitações naturais diferentes feitas para simular um usuário real.*

*O **Google** rastreia apenas `forms` que usam o método `GET` e não solicitam informações pessoais. **Além disso, o formulário deve ser composto de não mais do que dois campos de entrada.**"*

Fonte: https://www.sistrix.com/ask-sistrix/google-index-google-bot-crawler/can-the-google-bot-fill-out-and-crawl-forms/

Ainda sobre o campo Senha, veja o que diz o **Help Center** do Google:

> **Googlebot** and all other web crawlers are unable to access content in password-protected directories.

*"O **Googlebot** e todos os outros rastreadores da Web não podem acessar o conteúdo em diretórios protegidos por senha."*

Fonte: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93708?hl=en&ref_topic=4598466

Para completar aqui tem todos os tópicos do **Help Center** do Google sobre como bloquear o conteúdo dos Bots do Google. Talvez ali tenha algo que vc possa fazer uma "engenharia reversa" para identificar pq o conteúdo não é indexado pelo Google.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4598466?hl=en&ref_topic=4617736

Comment: Então analisei bem os links e vídeo que postou, fizemos algumas analises  e estudos aqui com o console do google e no ambiente de desenvolvimento e chegamos a conclusão de que realmente é isso, o fato do google não preencher o nosso form de acesso é por conta que o mesmo é um campo onde o usuário digita o nome de sua cidade e aparece uma lista no qual o mesmo tem que selecionar a cidade válida (um select que aparece de acordo com que o usuário digita), e por isso provavelmente o bot do google não consegue prosseguir para as páginas seguintes. Obrigado pelo apoio!

Comment: @MSLacerda essa é a teoria se revelando na prática rss. Legal vc ter vindo aqui compartilhar o resultado, pelo menos agora sabemos um pouco mais como esse bot realmente se comporta e suas limitações...